# slim logging not work

Tags: php, logging, slim

I use slim php framework and i want to log my exceptions in my custom error function, i follow the instructions on https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Extras. But it doesn't work like expected. I have opened a file inside my '../api/views' directory and write some bullshit to test. So my path is okay and the permissions are given.

Here is my code snippet

```
 $app = new Slim\Slim(array(
  'debug' => false,
  'log.enabled' => true,
  'log.level' => Slim\Log::DEBUG,
  'templates.path' => '../api/views',
  'slim.errors' => new Slim\Extras\Log\DateTimeFileWriter(array(
      'path' => '../api/logs',
      'name_format' => 'Y-m-d',
      'extension' => 'log',
      'message_format' => '%label% - %date% - %message%'
  ))
));

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
  $data = $app->render('index.php');
});

$app->notFound(function () use ($app) {
  $app->redirect('/');
});

$app->error(function(Exception $e) use ($app) {
  $app->log->error($e->getMessage());

  $app->response->setStatus(400);

  $app->response->setBody(
    json_encode(
      array(
        'code' => '401',
        'message' => $e->getMessage()
      )
    )
  );
});
```

Some one an idea or another solution to log? i have used different ways but nothing worked.

Here my composer.json

```
{
  "require": {
    "slim/slim": "2.6.2",
    "slim/extras": "^2.0",
    "slim/middleware": "^1.0",
    "twig/twig": "~1.0",
    "mpdf/mpdf": "^6.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "api"
    ]
  }
}
```

EDIT:
No exceptions or errors are thrown. Everything work like expected except the logging. It looks like slim ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is following:

The slime extras repo link to an slim logger repo https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Logger where you not append the writer to log.writer instead of slim.errors.

Now it works and i am happy :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `slim.errors` with `log.writer` in your config.